# Liferay Exception while deploying portlet with MappingExeption entity class not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liferay

I created a custom portlet in liferay and created a service builder with one entity and many columns and ordered them according to primary key and added 4 finder methods. I run the service builder and it didn't give any error and then deployed the portlet. In tomcat console I am getting this Exceptions and errors.

Following is the stacktrace which I'm getting on console

```
> 07:23:12,434 ERROR
> [localhost-startStop-8][PortletApplicationContext:138]
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
> Configuration proble m: Bean class
> [com.hiring.servicelayer.service.impl.ApplicationsDataLocalServiceImpl]
> not found_Offending resource: ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/p ortlet-spring.xml]_Bean
> 'com.hiring.servicelayer.service.ApplicationsDataLocalService'; nested
> exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.hiring.servicelayer.se rvice.impl.ApplicationsDataLocalServiceImpl
> [Sanitized]
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
> Configuration problem: Bean class
> [com.hiring.servicelayer.service.impl.ApplicationsDataLocalS
> erviceImpl] not found_Offending resource: ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/portlet-spring.xml]_Bean
> 'com.hiring.servicelayer.service.ApplicationsDataL ocalService';
> nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.hiring.servicelayer.service.impl.ApplicationsDataLocalServiceImpl
> [Sanitized]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:291)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:491)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:396)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:365)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:258)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:153)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(PortletApplicationContext.java:127)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:85)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:85)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:41)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:230)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.hiring.servicelayer.service.impl.ApplicationsDataLocalServiceImpl
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.util.FilterClassLoader.loadClass(FilterClassLoader.java:41)
>         at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.createBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.java:63)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.createBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:616)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:472)
>         ... 48 more 07:23:12,537 ERROR [localhost-startStop-8][ContextLoader:206] Context initialization
> failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in
> ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cla
> sses/META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not
> found: com.hiring.servicelay er.model.impl.ApplicationsDataImpl
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:85)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:85)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:41)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:230)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found:
> com.hiring.servicelayer.model.impl.ApplicationsDataImpl
>         at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:125)
>         at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:191)
>         at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:67)
>         at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:135)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
>         at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
>         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:64)
>         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
>         ... 39 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hiring.servicelayer.model.impl.ApplicationsDataImpl
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>         at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
>         at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:122)
>         ... 53 more 07:23:12,551 ERROR [localhost-startStop-8][HotDeployImpl:233]
> com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
> initializing Spring for hiring_application-
> portlethiring_application-portlet
> com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
> initializing Spring for
> hiring_application-portlethiring_application-portlet
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:44)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:230)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in
> ServletContext resource [/
> WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
> entity class not found: com.hiring
> .servicelayer.model.impl.ApplicationsDataImpl
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortletContextLoaderListener.java:85)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:85)
>         at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.SpringHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(SpringHotDeployListener.java:41)
>         ... 24 more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found:
> com.hiring.servicelayer.model.impl.ApplicationsDataImpl
>         at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:125)
>         at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:191)
>         at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:67)
>         at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:135)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
>         at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
>         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>         at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:64)
>         at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
>         ... 39 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hiring.servicelayer.model.impl.ApplicationsDataImpl
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>         at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
>         at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:122)
>         ... 53 more
```

Can somebody help me with this issue.

Regards,
Shahbaz Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by just undeploying and redeploying the respective portlet in liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Also the same issue - redeploying did not help, but I removed the portlet from server and restart Eclipse, then deployed the portlet again. Just removing and adding did not help. Somehow, Eclipse is caching some Java classes / classpath and could not detect them.